# Many user using one program (.exe) that includes datasets

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataset, exe, multi-user

I created a time recording program in vb.net with a sql-server as backend. User can send there time entries into the database (i used typed datasets functionality) and send different queries to get overviews over there working time. 
My plan was to put that exe in a folder in our network and let the user make a link on their desktops. Every user writes into the same table but can only see his own entries so there is no possibility that two user manipulate the same dataset. 
During my research i found a warning that "write contentions between the different users" can be occur. Is that so in my case? 
Has anyone experience with "many user using the same exe" and where that is using datasets and could give me an advice whether it is working or what i should do instead?

Comment: So the exe is a .net application stored on a network share and the database is Microsoft SQL Server hosted on a network server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server will handle all of your multi-user DB access concerns.

Multiple users accessing the same exe from a network location can work but it's kind of a hack. Let's say you wanted to update that exe with a few bug fixes. You would have to ensure that all users close the application before you could release the update. To answer you question though, the application will be isolated to each user running it. You won't have any contention issues when it comes to CRUD operations on the database due to the network deployment.

You might consider something other than a copy/paste style publishing of your application. Visual Studio has a few simple tools you can use to publish your application to a central location using ClickOnce deployment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Great information. I printed the ClickOnce stuff out and gonna work throu it now. Since deadline is on monday alteratively i will put that on the next version. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to add a simple shutdown-timer in the form, which alerts users to saving their data before the program close att 4 AM.
If i need to upgrade, i just replace the .exe on the network.
Ugly and dirty, yes... but worked like a charm for the past 2 years.
good luck!

Comment: If you read the question carefully, this is about a different problem than the one you are thinking of.